# Binding DataTemplate content

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding, datatemplate

I have the following `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
    <Button Click="Cell_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TBlock" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

And I use this `DataTemplate` as `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`, but I have to bind dynamically the `Text` Property of the `TextBlock` when I add a new column:

```
GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
column.CellTemplate = Resources["ButtonTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
// How to get the TBlock (TextBlock) of CellTemplate and bind its property here?
MyGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

What have I to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about modifying the template, you better create it from scratch in code (or you can use [`XamlReader.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse.aspx) and a XAML string with the binding code inserted dynamically) .

Comment: What is the string I have to parse?

Comment: @Nick: A string containing your datatemplate in XAML, search for the method name on SO and you will find examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an EventHandler for the TextBlock's Loaded-Event and create the binding there (based on the TextBlock's DataContext, if that is enough information).

Comment: The problem is that your template is not instantiated at the time you create the column, so you cannot use FindName. You'll have to wait until it is loaded. Then you you should be able to do it that way: http://marcozhou.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/how-to-reference-named-elements-within-celltemplate/

Comment: I have to bind the Text property to a property named `("Box" + MyGridView.Coulmns.Count)`. Can you make me an example to do this? In XAML if I write `Text={Binding Box1}` it works, but I have to chose dynamically what is the right name.